# *ngIf display item depending on database values

Tags: angular

I have a list of users, at the moment i'm displaying all of it, i want to display only the users with the attribute isAvailable=true

here's my array of objects

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okCOK.png)

```
<div *ngIf="????whatshould i put here?" class="users">
  <img  *ngFor="let user of users" class="user" src="data:image/bmp;base64,{{sticker.base64}}" (click)="addUser(user)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users" class="stickers">
  <img *ngIf="user.isAvailable"  class="user" src="data:image/bmp;base64, 
 {{sticker.base64}}" (click)="addUser(user)">
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately this acting weirdly , by swaping the ngfor and the ngIf, my elements are not aligned like before

Comment: Are you able to see the behavior you were expecting i.e only the available users getting displayed?

Comment: By acting weirdly, do you mean css issue?

Comment: Yes it broke the css

Comment: I fixed it, Thank you sir